# In laravel, How to display role name by role_id in user listing?

Tags: laravel

**USER MODEL**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'roles');
}
```

**ROLE MODEL**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Role::class, 'role_id');
}
```

**BLADE FILE**

```
<tbody>
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->country}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->state}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->city}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->role_id}}</td>
        <td>
            <button><a href="{{route('edituser', $user->id)}}">EDIT</a></button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="deleteuser" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">DELETE</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

`role_id` is foreign key in `users` table. please help me how to display role name while displaying users list.

Comment: As in you want to display the the role name where you have `$user->role_id`?

Comment: @Rwd Yes I want to display role name INSTEAD OF role_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes in your code. I hope it will work

**USER MODEL**

```
public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class,'role_id');
    }
```

**ROLE MODEL**

```
public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'role_id');
    }
```

**User Controller**

```
public function index(){

        $users = User::with('role')->get();
        return $users;
    }
```

**BLADE FILE**

```
<tbody>
   @foreach($users as $user)
      <tr>
          <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->country}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->state}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->city}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
          <td><button><a href="{{route('edituser', $user->id)}}">EDIT</a> 
          </button></td>
          <td><button class="deleteuser" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" data-token=" 
          {{ csrf_token() }}" >DELETE</button></td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

Comment: can you please help with country state and city also. foreign key is not defined for 3 of them

Comment: Every country has many states, and every state has many cities. so every city belongs to any state and state belongs to any country.
state having country_id,
as well as city having state_id,

Comment: Yes I have mentioned relationship

Comment: City Model:
public function state(){
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class,'city_id');
    }

State Model:
public function country(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class,'state_id');
    }

public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany(City::class,'city_id');
    }

Country Model:
public function states(){
        return $this->hasMany(State::class,'state_id');
    }

Answer (score 0):

You have reverse the way you define relationship between `User` and `Role` model it should be like this

```
class User extends Model {
    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
}

class Role extends Model {
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

With this kind of definition on the user model you should have define a `role_id` in the `create_users_table` migration.

and to display the role name you can perform it like this

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        {{-- other code goes here --}}

        <td>{{ $user->role->name }}</td>
        
        {{-- other code goes here --}}
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This presume a user can only have one single role

Comment: Can someone help me with country state and city also?? foreign key is not defined. How to display name instead of id??